# What capabilities can open /proc/pid/ns/net?

Tags: linux-capabilities

```
setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin,cap_sys_admin,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner+eip
```

I want a process running by normal user, switch to another process's netns, another process is running by root user. What I need to do is to open `/proc/pid/ns/net` and then call `setns`.
I have given many capabilities to the executable as above, but it still says `Permission denied`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need SYS_PTRACE and SYS_ADMIN capabilities.

This is documented in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html (the reference for SYS_ADMIN was already given in the other answer)

> The /proc/[pid]/ns/ directory
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>    Permission to dereference or read (readlink(2)) these symbolic
>    links is governed by a ptrace access mode
>    PTRACE_MODE_READ_FSCREDS check; see ptrace(2).
> ```

Answer (score 1):

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html suggests:

```
Network, IPC, time, and UTS namespaces
              In order to reassociate itself with a new network, IPC,
              time, or UTS namespace, the caller must have the
              CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability both in its own user namespace
              and in the user namespace that owns the target namespace.
```